# IPhone / iPad will not load website or subdomain hosting behind a AWL ELB

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, ipad, dns, amazon-elb

I ran into a difficult problem where a website hosted on an EC2 instance behind an ELB on AWS would not load on any mobile I-devices. The site loaded fine on all browsers on desktop.

My EC2 is running Centos with Apache.

There is no error message, Safari just displayed a blank page, and the address bar would clear. Chrome displayed the message "ERR_FAILED".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this issue for several days, and could not find much online so I wanted to share my solution.

I found that running

```
curl "https://example.com"
```

returned

```
HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

After some more research, I found that

> Application Load Balancers provide native support for HTTP/2 with
>   HTTPS listeners. You can send up to 128 requests in parallel using one
>   HTTP/2 connection. The load balancer converts these to individual
>   HTTP/1.1 requests and distributes them across the healthy targets in
>   the target group. Because HTTP/2 uses front-end connections more
>   efficiently, you might notice fewer connections between clients and
>   the load balancer. You can’t use the server-push feature of HTTP/2. [[source]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration)

**Solution:** edit http.conf to disable HTTP/2

change

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

to

```
Protocols http/1.1
```